# What does "Ich brauch mal Storno" mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, expression

Ich war heute bei Kaufland und habe

> blah blah... ich brauch mal Storno

gehört.

Bedeutet das so etwas wie "Kaffeepause" oder mehr in Richtung "Pinkelpause"? Oder ist die Bedeutung eine ganz andere?

(Obwohl ich [translation](/questions/tagged/translation) als Tag eingefügt habe, möchte ich die Antworten nicht unbedingt auf Englisch.)

Comment: Btw, the expression is colloquial and a nice example for *Sprachökonomie*; the full version is much longer: *"Ich brauche den Kassenschlüssel, um eine Stornierung durchzuführen."*

Comment: Related: Wikipedia: [Storno](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storno) and [Stornoschlüssel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stornoschl%C3%BCssel) (just for reference, everything important has been said in the answers already)

Comment: "Und hier kommt noch einmal ohne!" :-=)

Comment: @splattne: That "full version" borders on being artificially prolonged. "Ich brauche den Stornoschlüssel." or at least "Ich brauche den Stornierungsschlüssel." is already complete. Of course, you can always find a longer variant.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Is there really such a word as Stornoschlüssel? Or is a key which also can be used for other things, like the "Abschluss" at the end of the day?

Comment: @splattne: It's a composite noun. I don't see a necessity for composite nouns to be "words" in the sense of being defined somewhere (or else, I wouldn't be sure "Schrankschlüssel" or "Schubladenschlüssel" are words, either). Whether or not the key can *also* be used for something else should be irrelevant; if I mount appropriate locks, my "Hausschlüssel" can easily also serve as a "Schlafzimmerschlüssel" and a "Schrankschlüssel", without being less appropriately called "Hausschlüssel". Note how in hotels, a "Zimmerschlüssel" is sometimes also a "Hausschlüssel".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

„Storno“ steht für „Stornierung“ und bedeutet im Prinzip, dass eine Buchung/Rechnung rückgängig gemacht werden soll.

An Kassen ist dies oft der Fall, wenn ein Kassierer/eine Kassiererin irgendwas Falsches scannt oder eintippt oder wenn beispielsweise ein Artikel aus Versehen zweimal gescannt wird. In dem Fall muss der Artikel einmal wieder gutgeschrieben werden. Dazu sind Kassierer/Kassiererinnen aber normalerweise nicht befugt, daher bitten Sie dann eine höher gestellte Person (Abteilungsleitung, Filialleitung etc.) die Stornierung einmalig zu aktivieren. Oft ist das dann durch einen speziellen Schlüssel in der Kasse der Fall. Nach der Stornierung geht das normale Kassieren dann weiter.

Answer (score 9):

The cashier had scanned the wrong item and needed to cancel/void the transaction. So she was probably asking a colleague, presumably the manager, for a key that is needed to do that.